# Validating Vue syntax with W3C Validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, w3c-validation

I'm doing this course where I can freely select a framework to build a simple application. However, we are to validate the HTML with the W3C validator.

I have no idea how. The W3C validator does not support Vue-specific stuff. Errors such as:

```
Attribute v-for not allowed on element div at this point.
Attribute :key not allowed on element div at this point.
```

Is everywhere. And this is just for one line of code.

```
          <div v-for="mov in movie" :key="mov.id">
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I stupid or something? How on earth do I use W3C validator with Vue? Or any other framework that has attributes that deviates (thinking of "classname" in React).

Note that the W3C validator *must* be used, no other kind of validator.

Comment: And who’s mandated this? Vue templates are not HTML. They’re, well, Vue templates. They’ll get compiled to HTML, so you’ll need to validate the resultant HTML; not the template that is parsed by Vue.

Comment: Oh god. I forgot about getting the parsed HTML. I just assumed that the written HTML is to be validated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me being stupid.

Martin Bean commented:

> And who’s mandated this? Vue templates are not HTML. They’re, well, Vue templates. They’ll get compiled to HTML, so you’ll need to validate the resultant HTML; not the template that is parsed by Vue.

Which was the solution to the problem, or how you now may want to put it.